# Fixed Point Iteration Proof with Newtons method

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

Hey guys this is my question below

Let $$f:[a,b]\to  \mathbb R$$ 
be continuous on [a,b] and twice differentiable on (a,b) with $$f'(x) \neq 0 , f"(x) = 0, \forall x \in (a,b) $$

Suppose that
$$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \in [-(b-a),0], \forall x \in (a,b)$$

and there exists a constant k s.t
$$\frac{f(x)f"(x)}{(f'(x))^2} \leq k < 1, \forall x \in (a,b)$$

Use the fixed point theorem to prove that for any $$x0 \in [a,b]$$

Newton's iteration converges to the root of f in [a,b]

---

My attempt

This is what I know a fixed point is where $$x = g(x)$$ for a given function therefore the x value is the same as the functional value hence the name fixed point.

Therefore given a root of the equation p this will give the follwoing

$$g(p) = p$$

I know that there is a theorem that states the following if

$$ f \in C[a,b] and f(x) \in [a,b], \forall x \in [a,b]$$

then f has a fixed point in [a,b]

In addition if $$f'(x)$$ exists on (a,b) and there exists a positive constant k < 1 s.t.

$$|f'(x)| \leq k < 1$$ then the fixed point is unique.

Therefore my thinking is for newtons method given by the followng

$$x_{n+1} = x_n  - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

$$\implies$$

$$x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$$

Therefoe since f is continuous from the question

$$a,b > 0$$

$$b> a$$

based on the condition given $$|\frac{f(x)f"(x)}{[f'(x)^2]}| \leq k < 1$$

the function converges to  unique fixed point as

$$\frac{|f(x)f"(x)|}{|f'(x)^2)|} = 0$$

As well as

$$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \in [-(b-a),0]$$

$$\implies$$

$$f(x) > 0 $$

$$f'(x) < 0$$

Therefore since the derivative of the function is < 1 the fixed point is unique and converges to the root of f in [a,b] based on both conditions but im not sure if this would suffice to prove what is required. Can anyone tell me if this is correct and if not the method by which i prove it.

Comment: Something feels wrong. If $f''(x)=0$, then this is a line. Why even mention the existence of the constant $k$ as an additional hypothesis when it is obvious?

Comment: well im not sure but that was given in the question but i was wondering the same thing @zugzug

Comment: that would mean $$0 \leq k < 1 $$

Comment: I definitely see the point of the problem: To apply the two criteria of Banach's fixed point theorem. But the hypotheses don't make sense.

Comment: it says the second derivative is = 0 @zugzug i just checked the question back

Comment: any suggestions to proving what is required?

Comment: hey @zugzug you right the person told me that the second derivative is not equal to zero and that was a error can you help me with the solution.